# Сосед in genitive plural

Tags: conjunctions

Why is the word *сосед* declined as *соседей* instead of *соседов* since the stem ending is a consonant?

Comment: Let's hope someone gives a detailed answer but in a nutshell - there are nouns with irregularities in declension and you've stumbled across one of them. Your lessons don't seem to mention this at all.

Comment: I presume you know how to use [Wiktionary](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4) to check the declension forms. The noun *сосед* is marked as "тип склонения 1a^ по классификации А. А. Зализняка", where the ^ symbol means "особые случаи отклонений, нерегулярное словоизменение".

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/is-there-a-reason-why-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82-and-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%CC%81%D0%B4-dont-decline-for-nominative-plural-ac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just an exception. In Zalizniak's *Grammatical Dictionary* this word is marked with the △ sign:

- **сосе́д** мо 1a △ мн. сосе́д|и, -ей, -ям

[http://gramdict.ru/search/сосед](http://gramdict.ru/search/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4)

This word's stem gets softened in the plural: соседи, соседям, соседях (rather than *соседы, *соседам, *соседах) so the declension follows the soft pattern (as if the nominative singular were *соседь, similar to медведь, лебедь, жёлудь).

As to exactly why and how this exception came into existence, I have no information.  At least соседи is consistent throughout the plural. There are cases when softness is lost in just one form, genitive plural: башни - башен (not *башень) but деревни - деревень.